Flower petals offering
I remember reading somewhere that one should not take out the petals from flowers and offer entire flower on its own (for example: a flower with 10 petals, sometimes people separate and offer individual petals instead of offering entire flower in one go).
Please help with any related references which agrees or disagrees with flower petal offering instead of entire flower.
